# Error on adding web reference to WCF service from C++ project

Tags: c++, wcf

We have WCF service deployed, and attempt to add web reference to it from *native* C++ project (is written in VS2005) causes an error:

> Creating web service proxy file for NotificationReceiver1 ...
>
> sproxy : error SDL1000 : Unspecified error
>
> sproxy : error SDL1002 : failure in generating output file: "NotificationReceiver1.h"

Here is deployed WCF service configuration file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="NotificationService.NotificationReceiverBehavior" name="NotificationService.NotificationReceiver">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="NotificationService.INotificationReceiver" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NotificationService.NotificationReceiverBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This service can be opened with WebServiceStudio and is working fine (usually I use it for testing of web/wcf services)... But VS can't generate h-file ... why?

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you try to create it from command line using svcutil like:

svcutil.exe /language:cpp /out:NotificationReceiver.h /config:app.config http://localhost:8000/NotificationService

Comment: for native proxy try to use sproxy.exe, but if your client will be executed only in windows machine , i suggest you to use a managed proxy and use C++\CLI wrapper to use it from your C++ code.the proxy geneated by svcutil can treat all WCF possibilities unstead of native one.

Comment: Here I received error: SDL1002, some googling gave me the link to MicroSoft answer for that: http://connect.microsoft.com/wcf/feedback/details/425026/fail-to-add-web-reference-to-c-project-mfc-dll-project

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue. Unfortunately Native C++ Support for web services has been removed in newer releases of VS. 

Please contact Customer Support for a workaround to this issue in VC2005. Note also though that sproxy.exe did not support the latest WS-* protocols so it may be a limitation of the tool.

Another alternative may be using the Windows Web Services API that will release together with Windows 7 but it will be available downlevel as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435(VS.85).aspx